# Segue not started in ViewDidLoad / ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift

i try to run a Segue in my ViewDidLoad / ViewDidAppear method. I tried it in both methods but it didnt work. See my code attached:

```
      super.viewDidAppear(false)
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if (user?.isEmailVerified)!{
            print("started")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoMoin", sender: nil)
        }else  {

        }
    }
}
```

the mail is verified so i get the "started" output

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following code:

```
 let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if (user?.isEmailVerified)!{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoMoin", sender: nil)
    }else{
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: A better way would be `if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser { if user.isEmailVerified { //..`